# Superfast library for Android image caching

Tags: android, caching, android-imageview, image-caching

I looking for very fast Android image caching library. It's should support memory and disk caching, and also work fine with reusable views(such a ListView or GridView).

I've tried to use `Picasso` and `UniversalImageLoader`, but I want to add more speed. On the older devices GridView works slow. The problem is not in layout optimisation or heavy `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method, it's exactly in image cacher.

So what can you advise me on the basis of your experience?

Comment: Have you tried [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)?

Comment: As @Dmide mentioned, `LruCache`.

Comment: @bvitaliyg is asking for memory and disk caching libraries, how is LruCache even near a disk cache?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kaush's [UrlImageViewHelper](https://github.com/koush/UrlImageViewHelper). It support image downloading, caching etc.

Comment: Causes scroll lags in the GridView on Nexus 4 when image is loaded from disk or network.

But surprisely works good on the old devices.